# Active Directory seems to return cached information

Tags: c#, active-directory

We have an in-house windows console application that we use to update our Active Directory. This app has been running successfully for several years.

Recently I was tasked to add code to disable users that have not logged in to the system in over 90 days.

The code seems to be working correctly except that some users appear every time the app runs.

Here is the search code:

```
public SearchResultCollection SearchAD(string szSearchOU, string szSearchArg, string szObjectClass)
{
        if (szSearchOU == "")
        {
            ds.SearchRoot = c_DirectoryEntry;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!szSearchOU.StartsWith("LDAP://"))
            {
                szSearchOU = "LDAP://" + szSearchOU;
            }
            ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(szSearchOU);
        }

        string szFilter = "";
        if (szObjectClass == "")
            szFilter = "(objectClass=user)";
        else
            szFilter = "(objectClass=" + szObjectClass + ")";
        if (szSearchArg != "")
        {
            if (szSearchArg.Substring(0, 3) != "CN=")
                szSearchArg = "CN=" + szSearchArg;
            szFilter = "(&" + szFilter + "(" + szSearchArg + "))";
        }
        else
            ds.PageSize = 1001;
        ds.Filter = szFilter;
        SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();
        return results;
 }
```

This method is used throughout the application so I am reasonably certain that it works OK.

Here is the stub that calls the search and processes it:

```
SearchResultCollection src = SearchADUsers(szOU, "");
clsDisableLog.WriteLog("Processing: " + src.Count.ToString());
foreach (SearchResult r in src)
{
    DirectoryEntry deUser = r.GetDirectoryEntry();
    if (c_Debug)
        clsDisableLog.WriteLog("Processing: " + deUser.Name + " Path: " + deUser.Path.ToString());
    PropertyCollection userAttribs = deUser.Properties;
    int flags = (int)deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
    if (!Convert.ToBoolean((flags & UF_DISABLED) == UF_DISABLED))
    {
        bool bDisableAccount = false;
        DateTime dLastLogon = GetLastLogon(deUser);
        if (dLastLogon != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - dLastLogon;
            int iDaysSince = diff.Days;
            if (iDaysSince > iDays)
            {
                clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t" + deUser.Name);
                clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + "Has not logged in for " + iDaysSince.ToString() + " days.");
                clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + "Last logon date: " + dLastLogon.ToLongDateString() + " " + dLastLogon.ToLongTimeString());
                clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + deUser.Path.ToString());
                bDisableAccount = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t" + deUser.Name);
            clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + "Has never logged into domain.");
            clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + "Created: " + deUser.Properties["whenCreated"].Value.ToString());
            clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + deUser.Path.ToString());
            iAccountsNoLogin++;
        }
        if (bDisableAccount)
        {
            if (deUser.Path.Contains("UtilityAccounts"))
            {
                bDisableAccount = false;
                clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + "NOT Disabling Utility Account: " + deUser.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                if (UpdateUserFlag(deUser, UF_DISABLED, true))
                {
                    clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + "Disabled");
                    iAccountsDisabled++;
                }
                else
                    clsDisableLog.WriteLog("Error disabling " + deUser.Name);
                if (deUser.Path.ToString().ToLower() != deInactiveOU.Path.ToLower())
                {
                    if (MoveUser(deUser, deInactiveOU))
                    {
                        clsDisableLog.WriteLog("\t\t" + "Moved to: " + deInactiveOU.Name);
                        iAccountsMoved++;
                    }
                    else
                        clsDisableLog.WriteLog("Error moving " + deUser.Name + " to " + deInactiveOU.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There are about 14 accounts that are processed every time the app runs.

Example:

```
    2/25/2014 12:56:27 PM:  CN=XXXXXXXX
    2/25/2014 12:56:27 PM:      Has not logged in for 252 days.
    2/25/2014 12:56:27 PM:      Last logon date: Tuesday, June 18, 2013 10:14:45 AM
    2/25/2014 12:56:27 PM:      LDAP://CN=XXXXXXXX,OU=XXXX User Accounts,DC=XXXXXXXX,DC=LOCAL
    2/25/2014 12:56:27 PM:      Disabled
    2/25/2014 12:56:27 PM:      Moved to: OU=Inactive
```

After the app runs, this account IS IN OU=Inactive and IS disabled; however, if I re-run the app, the user shows up again, exactly as here!

Any suggestions?

I have set DS.CacheResults = false however the loop never executes at all if I do that.

Thanks,
John

```
    public bool UpdateUserFlag(DirectoryEntry deUser, int iFlag, Boolean bSet)
    {
        bool bReturn = false;
        int flags = (int)deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
        try
        {
            if (bSet)
                deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = flags ^ iFlag;
            else
                deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = flags & ~iFlag;
            deUser.CommitChanges();
            deUser.RefreshCache();
            bReturn = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsLog.WriteLog("Error updating user flag: " + deUser.Name);
            clsLog.Write(ex.Message);
            clsLog.WriteLog("");
        }
        return bReturn;
    }
    public bool MoveUser(DirectoryEntry deUser, DirectoryEntry deOU)
    {
        bool bReturn = false;
        try
        {
            deUser.MoveTo(deOU);
            deUser.CommitChanges();
            deUser.RefreshCache();
            bReturn = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsLog.WriteLog("Error moving: " + deUser.Name.ToString() + " to: " + deOU.Path);
            clsLog.WriteLog(ex.Message);
        }

        return bReturn;

    }
    public bool MoveUser(DirectoryEntry deUser, string szOU)
    {
        bool bReturn = false;
        try
        {
            deUser.MoveTo(new DirectoryEntry(szOU));
            deUser.CommitChanges();
            deUser.RefreshCache();
            bReturn = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsLog.WriteLog("Error moving: " + deUser.Name.ToString() + " to: " + szOU);
            clsLog.WriteLog(ex.Message);
        }

        return bReturn;
    }

    public DateTime GetLastLogon(DirectoryEntry deUser)
    {
        DateTime dtLL = DateTime.MinValue;
        try
        {
            if (deUser.Properties["lastLogonTimeStamp"].Count != 0)
                dtLL = GetDateTimeFromLargeInteger((IADsLargeInteger)deUser.Properties["lastLogonTimeStamp"][0]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            clsLog.WriteLog("Error Retrieving Last Logon Time Stamp for: " + deUser.Name.ToString());
            clsLog.Write(ex.Message);
            clsLog.WriteLog("");
        }
        return dtLL;
    }
```

As per one answer, I have posted the code for the methods called in the stub - although they are not relevant to the question because I have confirmed that they function as necessary. The accounts ARE DISABLED and they ARE moved to the relevant OU.

The issue is NOT that the code is not doing what it is supposed to do - it is that AD finds the users account NOT disabled and NOT in the OU even though I can confirm both using Active Directory Users and Computers.

John

Answer (score 0):

Why do this?

```
if (!Convert.ToBoolean((flags & UF_DISABLED) == UF_DISABLED))
```

This is already a boolean:

```
(flags & UF_DISABLED) == UF_DISABLED
```

Other than that it's hard to tell because all your stub does is call methods which you have not posted the code for.

Also a problem you might have is related to the fact that the `lastlogin` active directory attribute is domain controller specific, it is NOT replicated, therefore you must check every domain controller in the domain to see what the last logon date is.

Comment: @John No need to be rude, LastLogonTimeStamp is even worse as if you read the information it lags behind real time by 9-14 days with the default domain configuration. See https://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx.

Comment: @John Check the value of `UF_DISABLED` (which should be `0x2`) and  `int flags = (int)deUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;` returns the correct value because given your resulting output the issue must lie there.

Comment: const int UF_DISABLED = 0x0002;
According to http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx  the purpose is: Intended Use

It is important to note that the intended purpose of the lastLogontimeStamp attribute to help identify inactive computer and user accounts. The lastLogon attribute is not designed to provide real time logon information. With default settings in place the lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days behind the current date. - which is what we are trying to use it for.

Comment: Also, again, the issue is NOT that the account is not being deleted or moved - those are both happening. Also, we have over 1600 accounts in AD and only 14 of them are exhibiting this symptom.

Comment: To whoever voted me down: WHY. This is a legitimate issue and I have googled it repeatedly with zero results.

Comment: @John OK I understand that it doesn't matter in your case, but the problem MUST BE that `if (!Convert.ToBoolean((flags & UF_DISABLED) == UF_DISABLED))` returns `True` for those 14 accounts for whatever reason, or you wouldn't get the output your are suggesting. Find out why and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. You are correct: the account shows it is not disabled. However, in another part of this same program when I get the results for those users, it shows they ARE disabled. I have opened an incident with MS to help track down the discrepancy. Also, sorry for my earlier rudeness.